# set theory, show sets are not of equal cardinality - check my proof

Tags: elementary-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, proof-verification

question from exam in set theory:

let $M$ be the set of all real numbers x that satisfy: $cx^2+bx+a=0$ where $a,b,c \in Z$ (Meaning they are integers) and $c$ is not $0$.

We will define $K = \{sm+t | s,t \in Q, m\in M\}$

prove or deny that $|K|=|R|$ where $R$ is the set of all real numbers.

**My proof**:

let $A$ be the set of all algebraic numbers.

From the definition of M, we know that $M \subseteq A$

But since $A$ is a field with the functions addition and mulitiplication. So if $m$ is an algebraic number, and $s,t$ are rational numbers (a subset of the algebraic numbers) then $sm+t$ is also an algebraic number!

conclusion: $K \subseteq A$.

But we know that $|A|$ is aleph$0$ and that $|R|$ = $c$, so the statement that $|K|=|R|$ is false!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your proof is correct. Was there anything you weren't sure of? By the way, you can type the symbol $\mathbb{R}$ by `$\mathbb{R}$`.